# Logging into a forum with CURL (C++)

Tags: curl, managed-c++

I am trying to login into my website from a application in managed c++. I'm using curl to do this, and although I'm not receiving any errors, I'm confused on how to get the information needed to check whether the login was successful or not. I couldn't find someone with a similar issue as mine unfortunately, so I appreciate any help.

```
private: System::Void bLogin_Click ( System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e )
{
    if ( System::String::IsNullOrEmpty ( tbUsername->Text ) )
    {
        System::String^ str = gcnew System::String ( "Login failed! Please enter a valid username." );
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show ( str );

        return;
    }
    if ( System::String::IsNullOrEmpty ( tbUsername->Text ) )
    {
        System::String^ str = gcnew System::String ( "Login failed! Please enter a valid password" );
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show ( str );

        return;
    }

    using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

    curl_global_init ( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init ();
    if ( !curl )
    {
        curl_global_cleanup ();
        return;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L ); 
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L );  

    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0" ); 
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.myurl.com/member.php?action=login" );

    const char* szUser = static_cast< const char* >( Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi ( tbUsername->Text ).ToPointer () );
    const char* szPass = static_cast< const char* >( Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi ( tbPassword->Text ).ToPointer () );


    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Fmt::Fmt ( "username=%s&password=%s", szUser, szPass ) );
    //curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, Fmt::Fmt ( "%s:%s", szUser, szPass ) );

    std::string strData;
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback );
    curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &strData );


    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform ( curl );
    /* its always CURLE_OK */ 
    if ( res != CURLE_OK )
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show ( "A error has occured during the login process." );
    }

    Marshal::FreeHGlobal ( System::IntPtr ( reinterpret_cast< long long >( szUser ) ) );
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal ( System::IntPtr ( reinterpret_cast< long long >( szPass ) ) );

    /* check if suceeded here... but everything in strData is the same whether the credentials are right or wrong */


    curl_easy_cleanup ( curl );
    curl_global_cleanup ();
}
```

Also, my website came with "Wildcard SSL" but I'm not sure if that matters?
I'm pretty new to all of this so I'm sorry if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: doesn't look like c++ to me. like `System::String^ str =something`, the `^` character is an arithmetic operator, and should make your compiler throw a syntax error, i think...

Comment: it's managed c++

Answer (score 0):

Distinguishing between a successful login and a failed one totally depends on the reply offered by the server. As we don't know what web application is involved, we can't provide more precise info.

Secondly, using curl from a managed c++ project is very strange. You have access to the .NET framework which provides HTTP clients that are easier to use, avoiding all the manual cleanup/marshaling.

Comment: Thank you very much. I switched to using the WebRequest class, then added a "do_login" param, then I check if the result contains "logged in." It's working perfectly now! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the WebRequest class, as D. Jurcau suggested. Also, I added `action=do_login` to the params, then checking the strings if it succeeded